# Bluez commands in Bluedroid

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluez

I have an **Android 2.2 device** which allows me to run **Bluez commands** such as

```
hcitool scan
```

&

```
hciconfig
```

However since **Android 4.2.2** comes with **Bluedroid**, **how can I run such commands?**

I am looking for an alternative or a similar set of commands that can be used in Bluedroid.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Bluedroid has a different architecture than Bluez. Currently there are no such tools for bluedroid on android.