# bluetooth library for latest Android / Cyanogenmod?

Tags: android, bluetooth, adb, obex, obexftp

I am trying to build some of the bluetooth terminal tools such as hcitool and obexftp for Android with NDK. However, from what I understand, the libbluetooth.so, which was included in several Android implementations of hcitool, hcidump, obexftp no longer works since the bluetooth stack on most recent Android has changed.

Specifically, I need obexftp to be able to perform bluetooth ftp transfer between two Nexus 5 and OnePlus One phones. Here are links to few implementation of tools from 5-6 years ago which no longer work. I am getting error `Device not found`.

```
https://github.com/d34th4ck3r/Hcidump-in-Android
https://github.com/AlanZheng/hcidump-android
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=9993128
http://i-miss-erin.blogspot.com/2009/09/connect-bluetooth-keyboard-in-android.html
```

Does anyone know which libbluetooth.so file I need now or do I need other libraries to be able to use bluetooth stack?

My current phones have Cyanogenmod 12.1 and Android 5 Lolipop.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24605783/bluez-commands-in-bluedroid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BlueZ` (standard linux bluetooth stack) has been replaced with  `bluedroid` (originally by Broadcom, now open sourced) in Android 4.2.

There is no easy way to make old `bluez` tools work with the new stack.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that. I might try to do that port of bluez to make hcitool and obexftp work again.